# Getting pixel values from array of x,y points on an image using PIL getpixel

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

So I have an image, and I have a meshgrid of points of where I want to get RGB values from my image. I am using PIL's getpixel() and getting the error:

```
      return self.im.getpixel(xy)
TypeError: an integer is required
```

I think the issue is that my xy in getpixel is an array of x and y values, not integers. But how do I get it to give me all the rgb values at all those points then? Do I use something other than getpixel? My code looks like this:

```
xm = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, inputx)
ym = np.linspace(ymin, ymax, inputy)
xmr, ymr = np.meshgrid(xm, ym)
r, g, b = list(image1.getpixel((xmr, ymr)))
```

I get the error when I try to print r, g, b. How do I get it to give me an array of RGB values at all my given points on the meshgrid?

Answer (score 1):

You got an error because `getpixel` method expects one pixel at a time. An easier alternative, is to convert the image into a numpy array and get the values:

```
xm = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, inputx).astype(int)
ym = np.linspace(ymin, ymax, inputy).astype(int)
xmr, ymr = np.meshgrid(xm, ym)
img = np.array(img)
sub_image = img[xmr.flatten(), ymr.flatten()]
sub_image[0], sub_image[1], sub_image[2]
```

if you do want, however, to use `getpixel`, you can do the following:

```
vals = list(img.getpixel((int(x), int(y))) for x,y in zip(xmr.flatten(), ymr.flatten()))
r = [val[0] for val in vals]
g = [val[1] for val in vals]
b = [val[2] for val in vals]
r, g, b
```